# MediaRecorder Start failed -2147483648 working on 2.3 but not on 4.0

Tags: android, service, android-mediarecorder

```
audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ""+audio_format, sampleDir);
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;

recorder=new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(audioSource);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath()); 

//recorder.prepare(); 
//recorder.start();
//Handle IOException

  recorder.prepare();

  recorder.start();
  Log.d("TAG", "recording started");
```

the code work perfectly on android2.3 but not works on 4.0 it gives error on recorder.start() ,I am completely blank on this 
Any suggestion related to it will accepted ,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Try this maybe it will help

```
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
 private static final String LOG_TAG = "MediaAudioCapture";
 ImageButton button_audio_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.audio_button);
  button_audio_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View record_button) {
  ImageButton audio_button = (ImageButton) record_button;
  if (!started_note_recording) {
    if (!started_recording) {
      startRecording();
      audio_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_red);
     } else {
     stopRecording();
     audio_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
     }
    }
  }
 });
private void startRecording() {
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(output.getAbsolutePath());
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
ImageButton button_audio_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.audio_button);
button_audio_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
 }
}
});
 try {
  mRecorder.prepare();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}
mRecorder.start();
stopWatch.start();
}
```